# ASP.NET WebAPI multiple actions were found

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I have a web api controller and two GET methods:

```
public class ImagesController : ApiController {
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetImages() { }

    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Download([FromUri]int[] ids) { }
}
```

Why I'm getting multiple actions found error, when trying to reach /api/Images, why both actions are the same?

Answer (score 0):

When you created controller, you have assigned `HttpGet` to two different methods. Making that you have confused web server when it tries to process your request. Since you are sending `GET` verb to the controller it self, instead directly to the method, web server can not determinate what method should be invoked.

You can try with `/api/Images/GetImages` in order to directly hit a method, or remove one of listed.

Comment: But why the web server doesn't get confused if I have GetImages() and the following:   GetImagesById(int id) { }

Comment: `GetImages()` will return complete list of Images. And `GetImageById`, will return instance of a Image for given id.

Basically those are two different requests `/api/Images/` (GetImages) and `/api/Images/10` (GetImagesById).

Comment: But also if I use a request with query string                        (/api/Images?id=10) web server know how to deal with it, but why it doesn't know how to deal with that Download action. For example, if I leave only Download action, why I can send two different requests to him? /api/Images returns nothing (but it goes to action when debugging) and /api/Images?ids=1&ids=2 returns images with those ID's. My question is, why Download(int[] ids) and GetImages() together confuses web server, but GetImages() and GetImagesById(int id) doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

If you see the Web API feature it work for the selected httm methods like GET,PUT,POST,DELETE.

So if you create two action method with same name it will give error. To avoid this error you have to redefine the DefaultAPI path in route.config file.

Change it to 
API/{controller}.....

After changing this acces your API from browser like

Or

Mark as a answer if this resolve your issue.